# Properly using Not In clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here, the scenario is:

I have 4 tables

1. `Course`
2. `Student`
3. `Department`
4. `EnrollCourse`

While a student going to enroll a course a list of courses should be in dropdown from courses table. But course_id which are already in enroll_courses table shouldn't load in that courses dropdown. Because a student can't register single course 2 times. Here I'm using `not in` operation which will retrieve list of course_id which are not in enroll_courses table.

But I'm getting following error for the query:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'enroll_courses.course_id LIMIT 0, 25' at line 6

Here is query:

```
SELECT students.name, students.email,departments.name as d_name,
        courses.name as c_name
        FROM students JOIN departments on students.department_id=departments.id 
        JOIN courses on departments.id = courses.department_id
        LEFT JOIN enroll_courses on enroll_courses.course_id=courses.id 
        WHERE courses.id NOT IN (enroll_courses.course_id) AND students.id=8
```

Anyone who can help me to find the solution?

Comment: NOT IN  ( enroll_courses.course_id ) should be like this

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. Perhaps you want `NOT IN (sub-query)`.

Comment: What's the DDL of the `enroll_courses` table? There should be two columns, `course_id` and `student_id`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. There is two columns, 1. Student_id 2. Course_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to get the desired result, this is close to your original query:

```
SELECT  students.name ,
        students.email ,
        departments.name AS d_name ,
        courses.name AS c_name
FROM    students
JOIN departments
  ON students.department_id = departments.id
JOIN courses
  ON departments.id = courses.department_id
WHERE students.id = 8   
-- up to here it's all possible courses

-- now remove already enrolled courses
  AND courses.id NOT IN  
   (
     SELECT course_id
     FROM enroll_courses
     WHERE student_id = 8
   )
```

Or a Correlated version:

```
  AND courses.id NOT IN  
   (
     SELECT course_id
     FROM enroll_courses
     WHERE student_id = students.student_id
   )
```

Or NOT EXISTS:

```
  AND NOT EXISTS 
   (
     SELECT *
     FROM enroll_courses
     WHERE student_id = students.student_id
       AND course_id = courses.course_id
   )
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this,

```
SELECT  students.name ,
        students.email ,
        departments.name AS d_name ,
        courses.name AS c_name
FROM    students
        JOIN departments ON students.department_id = departments.id
        JOIN courses ON departments.id = courses.department_id
        JOIN enroll_courses ON enroll_courses.course_id = courses.id
WHERE   students.id = 8
        AND courses.id NOT IN ( enroll_courses.course_id );
```

Comment: How is this supposed to work, you join on `enroll_courses.course_id = courses.id` and then you check for `courses.id NOT IN ( enroll_courses.course_id`, both are the same and not the same?

Comment: I'm not getting any data from the above query you have suggested.